# Split data frame into chunk and assign names to chunks from vectors

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 5*n columns, where n is the number of categories listed in a vector. I want to break the data frame into chunks of 5 columns (eg. category 1 is columns 1:5, category 2 is columns 6:10) and then assign the category names from the vector to the chunks.

eg.

```
*original data frame*              *vector of category names*
X a b c d e a b c d e a b c d e    1 apples
1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0    2 oranges
2 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1    3 bananas
```

Will become

```
*apples*       *oranges*     *bananas*
X a b c d e    X a b c d e   X a b c d e 
1 1 0 0 0 1    1 0 1 0 1 0   1 0 0 1 1 0 
2 0 1 0 1 0    2 0 0 1 0 1   2 1 0 0 0 1
```

I can find a whole lot of information about splitting data.frames by rows, which is much more common to do, but I can't find anything about splitting a data frame into n chunks by *columns*. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could split your original_data_frame by column indices similarely:

```
df <- read.table(header=T, check.names = F, text="
X a b c d e a b c d e a b c d e
1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0
2 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1")
n <- 5 # fixed chunksize (a-e)
lst <- lapply(split(2:ncol(df), rep(seq(ncol(df[-1])/n), each=n)), function(x) df[, x])
names(lst) <- c("apples", "oranges", "bananas")
# lst
# $apples
#   a b c d e
# 1 1 0 0 0 1
# 2 0 1 0 1 0
# 
# $oranges
#   a b c d e
# 1 0 1 0 1 0
# 2 0 0 1 0 1
# 
# $bananas
#   a b c d e
# 1 0 0 1 1 0
# 2 1 0 0 0 1
```

I don't know if this is elegant, but it came to my mind, first.